# Creacion de botones por ciclo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Que tal, estoy hacienda un ciclo para que se cree cierta cantidad de botones y en efecto se crean pero no puedo hacer que cada 5 botones se haga un salto de linea, he intentado con una condicion if pero no funciona

```
// Declaramos el Button y un literal que nos servirá para hacer saltos de línea
            Button bt;
            Literal lt;

            // Por ejemplo crearemos 5 botones, 
            // pero nuestra fuente de información puede ser cualquier otra
            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            {
                // Inicializamos el botón
                bt = new Button();

                // Le asignamos un text
                bt.Text = "Botón " + i;

                // Hacemos que maneje el evento Click mediante la función bt_Click
                bt.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);

                // Inicializamos el literal y hacemos que sea un salto de línea HTML
                lt = new Literal();
                lt.Text = "<tr />";

                // Ubicamos ambos controles en el PlaceHolder que hemos puesto en nuestra página
                // El uso del PlaceHolder no es obligatorio ni mucho menos, 
                // podéis añadir los controles donde os haga falta: 
                // una Cell de un Table, un Panel, a la propia Page, etc.
                Panel1.Controls.Add(bt);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(lt);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

La declaracion de los controles debes ubicarlo dentro del loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{

    Button bt = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(...);
    bt.Text = "Botón " + i;
    bt.Click += new EventHandler(bt_Click);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Location = new Point(...);
    lt.Text = "<tr />";

    Panel1.Controls.Add(bt);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(lt);
}
```

analiza como se define la variable y se asigna la instancia al usar

```
Button bt = new Button();
```

no declares de forma global ya que estarias pisando en cada iteracion la instancia anterior, recuerda que los objetos se crear por referencia

Tambien recuerda asignar la propiedad `Location` de los controles, sino pareceran uno encima del otro

[Control.Location Propiedad](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Estuve leyendo el link que me proporcionaste y si no entendi mal, `Location` es solo para windows forms. Corrigeme si estoy mal